# Replace the string if it is a single character and not if followed by another character(s)

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a String(s).
String can be 
`var str='d   d   day'` or `'day d d '` etc.
I want to replace `d` by some number (say 1), if it is single. It should not be reflected it is followed by any other character .i.e in day

`'d   d   day'`---------> `'1   1   day'`

`'day d d '`------------->`'day 1 1 '`

Thanks

Comment: Regex with word boundaries: `/\bd\b/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\b[a-z]\b/g,'1');//any character

str.replace(/\bd\b/g,'1');//d specific
```

Comment: You need a global flag in that regex.

Comment: it is replacing only the first d, use global to regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`:

```
var str = 'd d day',
    split = str.split(' '),
    toReplace = 1,
    ret;
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i].length > 1) continue;
    split[i] = toReplace;
}
ret = split.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace d with one following space `str.replace('d ','1')`

or you can use following with regular expression

```
str.replace(/\bd\b/,'1 ')
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple replace loop

```
a = 'd d day'
b = a;
while (b.indexOf('d ') != -1){
 b = b.replace('d ', '1 ')
}
```

then you can reassign b to a;